# mimicking MVC DisplayExtensions methods (fun and confusion with lambdas)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, generics, lambda

I'm trying to develop my own editable data grid for MVC in a fluent interface usable in a View. My question is really about using lambdas, not about data grids, but the context might help for understanding my question. Anyway, I have some code that looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<AdamOneilSoftware.Models.Something>

@{
    var firstItem = Model.FirstOrDefault();
}
@(Html.DataGrid(Model)
    .CssClass("data")
    .TextBox(model => firstItem.Text)
    .TextBox(model => firstItem.Position)
    .Render())
```

This much compiles okay. You can see that I want to use lambdas to setting up columns of my data grid. The thing I don't understand is how to do anything with those lambdas in my data grid class. I have surmised that I need to compile/invoke the expression, but I'm stuck on the Invoke part. Here's what I have:

```
public DataGridBuilder<TModel> TextBox<TValue>(Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    var del = expression.Compile();
    // invoke the delegate?
    var result = del.Invoke(); // but this expects a TModel argument
    return this;
}
```

The Invoke call expects a TModel argument (according to the Func declaration -- I understand that). But this doesn't work--and rightly so:

```
var result = del.Invoke(TModel);
```

How do I form the TModel argument in the Invoke call? Or am I heading the wrong direction completely? The goal is to do something like what the DisplayFor and EditorFor methods do--render some HTML with some awareness of the target property's metadata (DataFormatString, Display label, and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the view's `Model` instance to pass as the parameter.

You can find that in `Html.ViewData.Model`.

Comment: thank you -- it took some additional figuring to understand how to apply your advice, but your suggestion pointed me in the right direction